# Extjs 7.0 Classic Mymask Message is loading and will disappear but only one user is not closing when screen renders

Tags: extjs

When a user has click on update or add on the form -> loadFormData: function, I have a message to let them know that the screen is loading.  When the form is successful I have the message to disappear.  But there is only one user it does not close, the screen displays the loading message.  I put a debugger in the function and watch the user start the message and fall into the success function.  But fails to close the message.  I have tried to reproduce on Chrome, Windows Explore and Edge and cannot reproduce.

```
loadFormData:function(id, history, callback){
     var historyID = 0;
    if(id==undefined) id = 0;
    if(history) historyID = id;
    this.getForm().reset();
    var myMask = new Ext.LoadMask(Ext.getBody(), {msg:"Loading..."});
    this.getForm().load({
        url:'fc.php',
        method:'POST',
        scope:this,
        params:{
            _C_A:this.loadDataController,
            _hid:historyID,
            _uid:id
        },
        success:function(form, action){
          this.formData = action.result.data;
            this.fireEvent('afterFormSaved');
            if(typeof(callback)=='function'){
                callback();
            }
            Ext.getBody().dom.lastChild.remove();
        },
        failure:function(form,action){
            Ext.getBody().dom.lastChild.remove();
            var myMsg = 'Something went wrong while fetching form data. Please contact support';
            if(action.result && action.result.msg) myMsg = action.result.msg;

            Ext.Msg.show({
                title:'Form failed to load',
                msg:myMsg,
                icon:Ext.MessageBox.ERROR
            })
        }
    });
  },`
```

I have tried to add a timeout but still fails in the success.

Comment: Have you considered using ExtJS own ways to display mask? I mean [Ext.Mask](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.6.0/modern/Ext.Mask.html) or using [mask](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.6.0/classic/Ext.Component.html#method-mask) / [unmask](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.6.0/classic/Ext.Component.html#method-unmask) methods?  Using `Ext.getBody().dom.lastChild.remove()` to manipulate dom directly can be problematic for many reasons.

Comment: No I did not try using Ext.Mask.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Use for Classic

```
Ext.getApplication().getMainView().mask('Loading...');
Ext.getApplication().getMainView().unmask();
```

Use for Modern

```
Ext.Viewport.mask('Loading...');
Ext.Viewport.unmask();
```

Explanation: All Components support mask

```
https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.7.0/modern/Ext.form.Panel.html?#method-mask
```

Also read `setMasked`

```
Component.setMasked({
    xtype: 'loadmask',
    message: 'My Message'
});
```

Other usecases are to set loading for a grid (it is a component) via mask

```
grid.setLoading('Retrieving data ...');
grid.setMasked('Retrieving data...');
grid.mask('Retrieving data...');
```

Overall code quality: It might be a good idea to get a code-review for your code. Your current code, is hard to read and does not following Sencha best practices. If you are not supporting IE9 you might consider using ECMA 6 basics.